# QGIS: Dissolving Polygons with Self-Intersection

Tags: qgis, dissolve, self-intersection

I have created multiple polygons with some subset of track-lines, with the order of time those points were recorded. Therefore some of the polygons have self-intersection within the polygon.

Is there any way to solve this self-intersection problem for dissolving polygons?

I used "Buffer" in "GeoProcessing Tools" with 0 distance and "Dissolve 
result". However, some of the polygons didn't merge into the same polygon (green in this picture). The bottom layer with brown polygons were my line-to-polygons constructed polygons.

[image]

Comment: Could you please make clearer, what your problem is?

Comment: Updated. The brown polygons didn't merge into the green polygons because of "self-intersection" (according to what the Error log)

Comment: In QGIS 3.x you can try using the "Fix Geometries" tool - I believe this fixes self-intersection issues.

Comment: why are you trying to make a polygon, this data is clearly a set of lines. - do you want the range of the animal - if so look at convex hull or alpha hull questions

Comment: i think indeed, that if it's a GPS track. You should try to make a line with the time attribute or either use a convex hull fonction of some cluster in your dataset to find the range of the movement. But tryng to make polygon straightforward is a bit clumsy